# How to remove clear button from IE7-9?

Tags: internet-explorer, button

I'm working with ExtJS 4.1.1 and I'm trying to remove IE's clear button from a number field. I'm able to achieve this in IE10 doing this :

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear{display:none;}
```

Now I'd like to do the same in other versions of IE... Any idea? Do think that IE10 version switcher may have something to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike IE10+, IE9 and prior don't display a "clear button" in HTML form fields. Are you trying to enable the page to run in IE7-IE9 mode *inside* IE10? If not, you don't need to do anything else.

If you *are* using the `X-UA-Compatible` declaration to run pages in IE7-IE9 mode inside IE10, you're stuck (no workaround) because the `-ms-clear` CSS rule is only supported in IE10 mode. (Many duplicates of that question here on StackOverflow)

Comment: Not really, I use IE 7-9 inside IE 10 for debugging purposes only, but I'd like to get the real result since I haven't got the original software. Anyway, I trust you :), I will check this by myself someday. Thanks.

Comment: you are right... I am in this situation and -ms-clear is not working...